# TextInput style is not updating if there is an emoji in text value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-textinput

TextInput style is not updating if there is an emoji in text value however without emoji the text value color is updating. I would like to know why this issue is happening? Is it react-native issue or I am doing something wrong?

```
React Native Environment Info:
System:
OS: macOS 10.14.6
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4258U CPU @ 2.40GHz
Memory: 151.51 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 11.2.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.15.2 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 12.4, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.4, watchOS 5.3
Android SDK:
API Levels: 27, 28
Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.0
System Images: android-27 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
IDEs:
Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338
Xcode: 10.3/10G8 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
react: ^16.8.6 => 16.8.6
react-native: 0.58.6 => 0.58.6
npmGlobalPackages:
create-react-native-app: 2.0.2
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.9
```

Please open the expo snack and write text with emoji and without emoji and you will see what's the issue right away.

https://snack.expo.io/@hamzashahbaz/textinput-error

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. this might be really react-native ios issue which you have already raised: github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25874

Comment: So it doesn't work only on iOS simulator. Have you tried it on real device maybe?

Comment: Try IOS and Android. https://snack.expo.io/@hamzashahbaz/textinput-error

Comment: Yes, I tried it on real devices. it is not working.

Comment: Looks like you have already raised this issue ~month ago: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25874.
Looks like this is really the issue with ios implementation of react-native as only on ios it doesn't work.

Comment: Getting the same issue on 0.62.2. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with emojis on an TextInput that was highlighting hashtags. After a few days, my solution was to remove this:

```
  [oldText enumerateAttribute:@"NSOriginalFont" inRange:NSMakeRange(0, oldText.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
    if (value){
      fontHasBeenUpdatedBySystem = true;
    }
  }];
```

from here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/Libraries/Text/TextInput/RCTBaseTextInputView.m#L112-L116

After that, I also used the patch-package and postinstall libraries to create a patch and apply it automatically after installing all the libraries.